# How can I use the content of a data attribute as a hash key?

Tags: javascript

I have a DOM element with :

```
data-update-attribute='name' data-update-url='users/1'
```

And I want to do something like this:

```
    $.ajax({ type: 'PUT',
        url: $el.data('update-url'),
        data: { user: { xxx: value } }
    });
```

My problem is that I cant figure out how to replace the xxx with the content from `data-update-attribute`. This would be trivial in Ruby but I am totally clueless about how to do it in JS :-S

Thanks!

Comment: Object literal labels can't be specified like that, AFAIK. Why not use two different keys instead of one?

Comment: this was a simplified version of my 'real' code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't in object literals, you will need to construct an object without the key and then use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators):

```
var url = $el.data('update-url'),
    attr = $el.data('update-attribute'),
    user = {};
user[attr] = value;
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: url,
    data: { user: user }
});
```